# qemu kvm permission denied error despite running as root

Tags: permissions, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I had qemu/kvm working perfectly. Then I rebooted one day and it would not work any more. It worked for maybe 1-2 years stably (ignoring hardware issues, has run nvidia and amd fine) until recently it started throwing permission errors. All I can think of is I installed openssh (+ufw) around the time it stopped working.

But why would this break qemu-kvm with a permission error when it is set up to run as root?

Is there a command I can run to see what is preventing it? I am out of ideas.

I have gone through all the instructions I used to set up the VM and I can't find a problem, as you would expect, I didn't touch the config files. I additionally tried changing dynamic ownership = 0 (was 1) in qemu.conf but it was not necessary before and did not fix the problem. I also tried to boot without vfio and yes the nvidia driver works OK, it's not a hardware issue. Which is what I expected as I've had hardware issues with amd and I didn't get a permission error, it just doesn't boot inside the VM, or the VM crashed later.

before it stopped working the log reads (/var/log/libvirt/gamingvm.log)

```
2019-04-14 04:15:32.147+0000: starting up libvirt version: 1.3.1, package: 1ubuntu10.24 (Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com> Wed, 23 May 2018 13:29:29 -0400), qemu version: 2.5.0 (Debian 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.34), hostname: freeman
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_PA_SAMPLES=128 QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name gamingvm -S -machine pc-q35-2.5,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu host,hv_time,hv_relaxed,hv_vapic,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd -m 16000 -realtime mlock=off -smp 6,sockets=1,cores=3,threads=2 -uuid 01bd2ed1-b465-4eba-b6e4-47c6ac8171c6 -nographic -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-gamingvm/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=localtime -no-shutdown -boot menu=on,strict=on -device i82801b11-bridge,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1e -device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=2,id=pci.2,bus=pci.1,addr=0x1 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.2,addr=0x4 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb1,bus=pci.2,addr=0x5 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb2,bus=pci.2,addr=0x6 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb3,bus=pci.2,addr=0x7 -drive file=/home/free/VM/Win7/Win7.img,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-sata0-0-0 -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=drive-sata0-0-0,id=sata0-0-0,bootindex=2 -drive file=/home/free/VM/Win7/W10X64.MULTi7.RS2.APR2017.ISO,format=raw,if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-sata0-0-1,readonly=on -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=drive-sata0-0-1,id=sata0-0-1,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=26,id=hostnet0 -device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:36:3b:c4,bus=pci.2,addr=0x1 -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -device AC97,id=sound0,bus=pci.2,addr=0x2 -soundhw ac97 -device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on -cpu host,kvm=off -msg timestamp=on
Domain id=1 is tainted: high-privileges
Domain id=1 is tainted: custom-argv
Domain id=1 is tainted: host-cpu
2019-04-14T04:24:37.110750Z qemu-system-x86_64: terminating on signal 15 from pid 1248
2019-04-14 04:24:39.913+0000: shutting down
2019-04-14 04:24:49.146+0000: shutting down
```

--- normal ran for 10 minutes

```
   2019-04-14 04:25:22.871+0000: starting up libvirt version: 1.3.1, package: 1ubuntu10.24 (Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com> Wed, 23 May 2018 13:29:29 -0400), qemu version: 2.5.0 (Debian 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.34), hostname: freeman
    LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_PA_SAMPLES=128 QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name gamingvm -S -machine pc-q35-2.5,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu host,hv_time,hv_relaxed,hv_vapic,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd -m 16000 -realtime mlock=off -smp 6,sockets=1,cores=3,threads=2 -uuid 01bd2ed1-b465-4eba-b6e4-47c6ac8171c6 -nographic -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-gamingvm/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=localtime -no-shutdown -boot menu=on,strict=on -device i82801b11-bridge,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1e -device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=2,id=pci.2,bus=pci.1,addr=0x1 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.2,addr=0x4 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb1,bus=pci.2,addr=0x5 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb2,bus=pci.2,addr=0x6 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb3,bus=pci.2,addr=0x7 -drive file=/home/free/VM/Win7/Win7.img,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-sata0-0-0 -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=drive-sata0-0-0,id=sata0-0-0,bootindex=2 -drive file=/home/free/VM/Win7/WIN7X64.OEM.ENU.FEB2019.iso,format=raw,if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-sata0-0-1,readonly=on -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=drive-sata0-0-1,id=sata0-0-1,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=27,id=hostnet0 -device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:36:3b:c4,bus=pci.2,addr=0x1 -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -device AC97,id=sound0,bus=pci.2,addr=0x2 -soundhw ac97 -device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on -cpu host,kvm=off -msg timestamp=on
    Domain id=3 is tainted: high-privileges
    Domain id=3 is tainted: custom-argv
    Domain id=3 is tainted: host-cpu
    2019-04-14T06:38:03.272728Z qemu-system-x86_64: terminating on signal 15 from pid 1248
    2019-04-14 06:38:05.075+0000: shutting down
```

-- normal ran for 2 hours

```
2019-04-24 22:26:52.873+0000: starting up libvirt version: 1.3.1, package: 1ubuntu10.24 (Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com> Wed, 23 May 2018 13:29:29 -0400), qemu version: 2.5.0 (Debian 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.34), hostname: freeman
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_PA_SAMPLES=128 QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name gamingvm -S -machine pc-q35-2.5,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu host,hv_time,hv_relaxed,hv_vapic,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd -m 16000 -realtime mlock=off -smp 6,sockets=1,cores=3,threads=2 -uuid 01bd2ed1-b465-4eba-b6e4-47c6ac8171c6 -nographic -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-gamingvm/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=localtime -no-shutdown -boot menu=on,strict=on -device i82801b11-bridge,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1e -device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=2,id=pci.2,bus=pci.1,addr=0x1 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.2,addr=0x4 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb1,bus=pci.2,addr=0x5 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb2,bus=pci.2,addr=0x6 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb3,bus=pci.2,addr=0x7 -drive file=/home/free/VM/Win10/Win10.img,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-sata0-0-0 -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=drive-sata0-0-0,id=sata0-0-0,bootindex=2 -drive file=/home/free/VM/Win10/W10X64.MULTi7.RS2.APR2017.ISO,format=raw,if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-sata0-0-1,readonly=on -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=drive-sata0-0-1,id=sata0-0-1,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=26,id=hostnet0 -device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:36:3b:c4,bus=pci.2,addr=0x1 -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -device AC97,id=sound0,bus=pci.2,addr=0x2 -soundhw ac97 -device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on -cpu host,kvm=off -msg timestamp=on
Domain id=1 is tainted: high-privileges
Domain id=1 is tainted: custom-argv
Domain id=1 is tainted: host-cpu
2019-04-24T22:26:53.162911Z qemu-system-x86_64: cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Cannot allocate memory
```

--- normal - didn't run on boot straight away so something else has already allocated ram - I allocate 16GB out of 24GB so if general use means >8gb is already in use by the time I try and run the VM it fails, just means I have to run the VM soon after boot, so I rebooted:

```
2019-04-24 22:29:02.749+0000: starting up libvirt version: 1.3.1, package: 1ubuntu10.24 (Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com> Wed, 23 May 2018 13:29:29 -0400), qemu version: 2.5.0 (Debian 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.34), hostname: freeman
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_PA_SAMPLES=128 QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name gamingvm -S -machine pc-q35-2.5,accel=kvm,usb=off -cpu host,hv_time,hv_relaxed,hv_vapic,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd -m 16000 -realtime mlock=off -smp 6,sockets=1,cores=3,threads=2 -uuid 01bd2ed1-b465-4eba-b6e4-47c6ac8171c6 -nographic -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-gamingvm/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=localtime -no-shutdown -boot menu=on,strict=on -device i82801b11-bridge,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1e -device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=2,id=pci.2,bus=pci.1,addr=0x1 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.2,addr=0x4 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb1,bus=pci.2,addr=0x5 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb2,bus=pci.2,addr=0x6 -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb3,bus=pci.2,addr=0x7 -drive file=/home/free/VM/Win10/Win10.img,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-sata0-0-0 -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=drive-sata0-0-0,id=sata0-0-0,bootindex=2 -drive file=/home/free/VM/Win10/W10X64.MULTi7.RS2.APR2017.ISO,format=raw,if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-sata0-0-1,readonly=on -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=drive-sata0-0-1,id=sata0-0-1,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=26,id=hostnet0 -device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:36:3b:c4,bus=pci.2,addr=0x1 -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -device AC97,id=sound0,bus=pci.2,addr=0x2 -soundhw ac97 -device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on -cpu host,kvm=off -msg timestamp=on
Domain id=1 is tainted: high-privileges
Domain id=1 is tainted: custom-argv
Domain id=1 is tainted: host-cpu
shm_open() failed: Permission denied
Failed to create secure directory (/root/.config/pulse): Permission denied
2019-04-24T22:29:03.119665Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: vfio: error opening /dev/vfio/1: Permission denied
2019-04-24T22:29:03.119682Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: vfio: failed to get group 1
2019-04-24T22:29:03.119694Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: Device initialization failed
```

Permission denied!?

OK so it worked on 14 and failed 24 April. I checked what did I install between 14 and 24 April?
I installed Openssh, which also installed ufw firewall

I have been running this install for years, all the software I want is already installed. The last change before that was nearly a month prior. It's very likely to be related. But it makes no sense to me, openssh or ufw locking out my nvidia hardware or shm_open??? unless it adds security somehow???

grep install /var/log/dpkg.log

```
2019-04-22 17:14:17 status half-installed openssh-client:amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6
2019-04-22 17:14:17 status half-installed openssh-client:amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6
2019-04-22 17:14:17 install openssh-sftp-server:amd64 <none> 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8
2019-04-22 17:14:17 status half-installed openssh-sftp-server:amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8
2019-04-22 17:14:17 install openssh-server:amd64 <none> 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8
2019-04-22 17:14:17 status half-installed openssh-server:amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8
2019-04-22 17:14:18 status installed man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2019-04-22 17:14:18 status installed systemd:amd64 229-4ubuntu21.15
2019-04-22 17:14:18 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-19
2019-04-22 17:14:18 status installed ufw:all 0.35-0ubuntu2
2019-04-22 17:14:18 status installed openssh-client:amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8
2019-04-22 17:14:18 status installed openssh-sftp-server:amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8
2019-04-22 17:14:19 status installed openssh-server:amd64 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8
2019-04-22 17:14:19 status installed systemd:amd64 229-4ubuntu21.15
2019-04-22 17:14:19 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-19
2019-04-22 17:14:19 status installed ufw:all 0.35-0ubuntu2
2019-04-25 00:39:44 install libapr1:amd64 <none> 1.5.2-3
```

vfio is collecting the card before a graphics driver as it is supposed to.
And as you can see from the logs the software version did not change.

dmesg |grep vfio

```
[    5.466467] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
[    5.484052] vfio_pci: add [10de:1b06[ffff:ffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
[    5.508051] vfio_pci: add [10de:10ef[ffff:ffff]] class 0x000000/00000000
[   38.558212] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
[   38.576093] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
```

please note attempted to start VM at 38.5

lspci -v

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 120f
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at df000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf is set up correctly as

user = "root"

group = "root"

clear emulator capabilities = 0

dynamic ownership = 0 (was 1, I did change this to try and fix this problem)

cgroup_device_acl = [ includes /dev/vfio/1

nographics_allow_host_audio = 1

vnc_allow_host_audio = 1

dmesg log: (starting vm at 14172)

```
[14072.847851] Valid eCryptfs headers not found in file header region or xattr region, inode 26478193
[14172.505320] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
[14172.524948] vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=none
[14173.184929] virbr1: port 1(vnet0) entered blocking state
[14173.184932] virbr1: port 1(vnet0) entered disabled state
[14173.184999] device vnet0 entered promiscuous mode
[14173.201093] virbr1: port 1(vnet0) entered blocking state
[14173.201099] virbr1: port 1(vnet0) entered listening state
[14174.008430] L1TF CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See CVE-2018-3646 and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/l1tf.html for details.
[14174.078791] virbr1: port 1(vnet0) entered disabled state
[14174.079475] device vnet0 left promiscuous mode
[14174.079478] virbr1: port 1(vnet0) entered disabled state
```

Any ideas?

Comment: KVM guests are (for their extra risk of breaking out to the host) guarded by apparmor. The apparmor profiles are based on a template plus rules generated based on the guest definition. I'd expect you have hit an apparmor deny, could you please check dmesg while starting your guest and report and denies here?

Comment: log appended to question - thanks for your assistance